# interpolate onto a new time vector

Tags: r, interpolation

Is there a method for interpolating a time series onto a new one. For example:

```
data(co2)

Mauna <- as.numeric(window(co2, start = c(1991,1), end=c(1991,12)))
time = seq(from=as.Date("1991-01-01"), to=as.Date("1991-12-01"), length=12)

newTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct("1991-01-01 00:00"), to=as.POSIXct("1991-12-31 23:00"), length=8760)
```

From this I would like to interpolate the Mauna data onto the new time vector thus increasing the number of measurements in Mauna to 8760. Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `approx()` for a linear interpolation:

```
MaunaLinear <- approx(Mauna,n=8760)$y
plot(newTime,MaunaLinear)
```

Try the `spline()` function for a smoothed interpolation:

```
MaunaSmooth <- spline(Mauna,n=8760)$y
plot(newTime,MaunaSmooth)
```